# Virtual Contacts in Android

Tags: android, contacts

#### Short question regarding virtual contacts in Android.

Is it possible to have an Android Service Application (Background Process) to be able to provide contacts on the fly to the contacts application.

Also, to be able to provide these virtual contacts within the search results.

My idea is to extend the contacts application by providing dynamic contacts from the web during a contact search.

Is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

The People app on "pure Google" versions of Android (for example, Nexus 4) doesn't support this. The contacts have to be *somewhere* in the Contacts Provider. Of course, you can have your own account type and sync contacts from somewhere on the web to the Contacts Provider, and then the contacts will be treated the same as contacts added from the Google Contacts web app.

Your proposed app might be less useful than you think. What happens when the device doesn't have connectivity? If you sync your contacts to the device, then they're always available. The "cloud" is great, of course; you just have to ask yourself if cloud-only is going to be useful.